# Decoding an API list and breaking it up in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, split

I'm hoping to get your help on decoding a response I'm getting from an API into Python 3, and break it down into variables.  It's *almost* a list, see for yourself:

API returns this:

```
['b', "[[1465617600000,591.41,651.95,587.96,647.45,1474960.0,240144.89982940466],[1465704000000,647.2,700.68,644.09,698.55,1605710.0,242030.50812923996]]'"]
```

I'll assign that to lets say.. variable apiReturn.  I'm trying to break all the numbers down into individual variables, specifically with the formatting.
I'd like to do something like:

```
print(apiReturn[0][0])
```

and get:

1465185600000

Just playing around with trying to print that data here, to no avail:

```
print(apiReturn.split("'"))
print(apiReturn.split("'"[0][0]))
print(apiReturn.split("[", 1 )[1][0])
```

Comment: If that's an API, it's probably JSON. If the trailing `]` is actually missing, find an API that doesn't send you broken data.

Comment: Well that would be nice, but it isn't an option.

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: Can you add the code that gets the data?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

api_return =  apiReturn[1][:-1] # [:-1]: is there an extra quote trailing the second item?
# '[[1465185600000,589.02,600.0,585.01,591.78,401760.0,67821.2330781393],[1465272000000,592.31,595.45,570.32,581.12,396206.0,67722.36141861044]]'

api_val = ast.literal_eval(api_return)

print(api_val[0][0])
# 1465185600000
```

Comment: This will break with the slightest change, including the API actually working correctly